# Finding the probability mass function of a uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

> The number of letters, $X$, delivered to our home each day is uniformly distributed between $3$ and $10$. Find the probability mass function.

A little unsure about this question. But would the pmf be
$\frac{1}{8}$ (with a domain between $3$ and $10$)?

Comment: How did you get to $\frac{1}{8}$?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to understand that for a uniform distribution, the probability density function is a constant between the bounds $a$ and $b$. (Let $a \le b$)

The total area under a probability curve must equal $1$.

Notice that we can create a rectangle of width $b-a$ and height $h$, with $h$ being what we want to find. This area must equal $1$.

Setting up an equation for the area gives $$(b-a)h = 1$$

Think you can plug in $a$ and $b$ for your example and continue from here?

Comment: okay. So the pmf ends up being 1/7 with a bound between 3 and 10 correct?

Comment: That is correct. Also it would be good to note that if $x$ is not between $3$ and $10$ then the probability is equal to $0$.

Comment: Alright. One last question. Would the 3 and 10 be included within the bound or are they exclusive?

Comment: These would be included in the bound. It doesn't specify in your problem but general rule of thumb: they are inclusive.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help